# Getting location using LiveData and FusedLocationProviderClient

Tags: java, android, location-services

My goal is to get the location when the app starts, and if the user navigates away and comes back, to receive one location update and that's it. I am worried about removing the observer in the `getLocationUpdates` method.

**BoundLocationManager.class**

```
public class BoundLocationManager extends LiveData<Location> {

    private static BoundLocationManager instance;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    public static BoundLocationManager getInstance(Context appContext) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new BoundLocationManager(appContext);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private BoundLocationManager(final Context appContext) {
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(appContext);
        createLocationRequest();
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                    setValue(task.getResult());
                } else {
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, null);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                if (location != null)
                    setValue(location);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();
        if (mLocationCallback != null)
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
    }

}
```

**WeatherFragment.class**

```
private void getLocationUpdates() {
        BoundLocationManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).observe(this, new Observer<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    getWeather(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    getAddress(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    BoundLocationManager.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).removeObserver(this);
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

And finally I use it:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        else {
            getLocationUpdates();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get great answers.

Comment: @Phrancis Thank you very much for the encouragement! Have a great day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me explain how to work with `LiveData` - `ViewModel` and `Activity`.

Right now your `BoundLocationManager` looks good. I'd recommend not to make it's singleton. And also not consuming it directly in your UI (in this case `WeatherFragment`) code.

It's highly recommended to keep `LiveData` in `ViewModel` and your `ViewModel` will provide it the UI.

Also if you use `LiveData`, then never worry about removing the observer. It's done automatically for you.

Let me know if you still have some queries.

Comment: You save me everywhere :) everything is perfectly clear, but, I remove the observer because I only want to receive one update from the location service, otherwise everytime the user moves the location will be updated. That is why I unregister the observer straight away.

Comment: Haha no problem at all. Take a look at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java, I think it's useful if you want to receive one update.